# node.js получить вывод

Tags: node.js, asterisk

Библиотека [node.js asterisk](https://github.com/pipobscure/NodeJS-AsteriskManager)

Код

```
module.exports = require('asterisk-manager/lib/ami.js');
/**
 * port:  port server
 * host: host server
 * username: username for authentication
 * password: username's password for authentication
 * events: this parameter determines whether events are emited.
 **/
var ami = new require('asterisk-manager')('5038','ip','admin','ssss', true); 

// In case of any connectiviy problems we got you coverd.
ami.keepConnected();

// Perform an AMI Action. A list of actions can be found at
// https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+AMI+Actions
ami.action({
  'action':'originate',
  'channel':'SIP/myphone',
  'context':'default',
  'exten':1234,
  'priority':1,
  'variable':{
    'name1':'value1',
    'name2':'value2'
  }
}, function(err, res) {});

console.log(ami.action);
```

Результат выполнения в консоли "[Function]"

Каким образом мне получить результат выполнение команды? Результат возвращается в виде строки

Comment: Очевидно, в коллбэке ami.action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли вызвать функцию, те дописать **()**

`console.log(ami.action());`

Поэтому console.log возвращает Function. А результат выполнения функции в данном примере судя по всему должен храниться в **res**

```
}, function(err, res) { console.log(res); });
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло